# FB.ui Share popup on Azure Hosted Application: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains

Tags: azure, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have an application I have been developing which is to make use of the Facebook Developers FB.ui share popup:

```
        FB.ui({
            display: 'popup',
            method: 'share',
            href: imgUrl,
            quote: imgComment,
        }, function (response) { });
```

This seems to work perfectly when I am developing on localhost:5001 (I have set the following in my FB Dev Application settings):

[image]

However, as soon as I publish my application to my Azure hosted site (on the other address I have marked out above) I get the following error when trying to load the FB.ui Share popup:

[image]

The URL in the **Valid OAuth Redirects URIs** matches exactly the location of my Application online on Azure:

[image]

so cannot figure out why I am seeing this error when trying to load the Share popup.

Comment: _"The URL in the Valid OAuth Redirects URIs matches exactly [...]"_ - the error message did not talk about that field ... Settings -> Basic -> App Domains.

Comment: Thank you so much... I knew it would be something simple! Still figuring this all out. Many thanks for that!

Comment: p.s. if you wanted to add a more formal Answer to the question I will mark it as the accepted answer. If not, I will just add one myself. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The URL in the Valid OAuth Redirects URIs matches exactly the location of my Application online on Azure

The error message wasn't talking about that field, but about the *App Domains* field.

You find that under Settings -> Basic.